# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES): Trying to install MySQL

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to install MySQL to my computer, and I am following these steps. 
After I install and start MySQL, I Go back to Terminal and type:

```
    sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

Terminal asks me to type my password, then I type my Mac PW, and then I get this error:

```
    Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I apologize in advance, I am a beginner and have NO idea what to do next. I've done some research online and can't quite figure it out.

here's a link to the steps I'm following. I am stuck on Install MySQL # 9: 
https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

Comment: once you install root user is created with no password so try to run without password mysql -u root

Comment: MySQL >=5.7 will init a temp-password for root@localhost and log in the error-log.  Or without password if MySQL <=5.6, just try as vinay chhabra said.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Grants

mysql> show grants;

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION   |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

2 rows in set (0.07 sec)

if no set then set them with:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;